# How to show all the labels in subplot. I have 12 labels of which I have to plot a confusion matrix. But only 6 of them are visible

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, subplot, confusion-matrix

I want to plot a confusion matrix of 12 data, So I made 12 labels to plot the confusion matrix, the plot is coming correctly with the 12 data but x labels and y labels are only half-shown.

I used this snippet--:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

labels = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12']
cm = confusion_matrix(actualList, predictList, labels)
print(cm)
fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_figheight(10)
fig.set_figwidth(10)
ax = fig.add_subplot()
cax = ax.matshow(cm)
plt.title('Confusion matrix of the classifier',pad=-570)
fig.colorbar(cax)
ax.set_xticklabels([''] + labels)
ax.set_yticklabels([''] + labels)
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=30, ha="left",
         rotation_mode="anchor")
plt.xlabel('Predicted')
plt.ylabel('True')
plt.show()
```

and got this output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have more than a few categories, matplotlib will label the axes incorrectly. To fix this problem, you can import MultipleLocator from matplotlib.ticker to force every cell to be labelled.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator;

# the same values in your confusion matrix
labels = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12']
cm = [[0, 0, 61, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1099, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 131, 23, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 36, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 40, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 43, 0, 0, 0, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 269, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 86, 0, 0, 6],
    [0, 0, 101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 45, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 283, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 204]]

fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_figheight(10)
fig.set_figwidth(10)
ax = fig.add_subplot()
cax = ax.matshow(cm)
plt.title('Confusion matrix of the classifier',pad=-570)
fig.colorbar(cax)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1))
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1))

ax.set_xticklabels([''] + labels)
ax.set_yticklabels([''] + labels)
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=30, ha="left",
         rotation_mode="anchor")
plt.xlabel('Predicted')
plt.ylabel('True')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Glad to hear! I would probably use a seaborn heatmap in the future, but it doesn't hurt to know this hack in matplotlib

Comment: Matplotlib does not label the axes incorrectly.  It chooses a reasonable number of ticks and displays those.  Imagine your matrix was 10000x10000. you probably don’t want 10000 ticks.